# How to Read a parquet file , change datatype and write to another Parquet file in Hadoop using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

My source parquet file has everything as string. My destination parquet file needs to convert this to different datatype like int, string, date etc. How do I do this?

Comment: You should provide what you've tried and what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may wanted to apply userdefined schema to speedup data loading.
There are 2 ways to apply that-

### using the input DDL-formatted string

```py
spark.read.schema("a INT, b STRING, c DOUBLE").parquet("test.parquet")
```

### Use StructType schema

```py
customSchema = StructType([
        StructField("a", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("b", StringType(), True),
        StructField("c", DoubleType(), True)])
spark.read.schema(customSchema).parquet("test.parquet")
```

Comment: parquet stores column data type in the file unlike csv. So how does specifying schema speedup the data load?

Answer (score 2):

You should read the file and then typecast all the columns as required and save them

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.read.parquet('/path/to/file')
df = df.select(col('col1').cast('int'), col('col2').cast('string'))
df.write.parquet('/target/path')
```

Answer (score 0):

Data File:
| data_extract_id| Alien_Dollardiff| Alien_Dollar

|ab1def1gh-123-ea0|               0|           0

Script:

```
def createPrqtFParqt (datPath, parquetPath, inpustJsonSchema, outputdfSchema):
  print("## Parsing " + datPath)
  df = ssc.read.schema(outputdfSchema).parquet(datPath)
  print("## Writing " + parquetPath)
  df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(parquetPath)
```

Output:
An error occured while calling Parquet.
Column: Alien_Dollardiff| Expected double Found BINARY.